# cant see the .csv file when uploading

Tags: php, mysql, csv

am trying to upload a field to a mysql database. the field can be uploaded by the user typing it manually or uploading a .csv file that contains the field. the manual typing works well but when i try to upload using a .csv it does not see the file and skips to the "else" segment of my code. this is my code:

```
<?php
    $classname = $_POST['classname'];
    $classname = stripslashes($classname);
    $classname = mysql_real_escape_string($classname);


    $save = $_POST['save'];
    $save = stripslashes($save);
    $save = mysql_real_escape_string($save);


    $myfile = $_POST['myfile'];
    $myfile = stripslashes($myfile);
    $myfile = mysql_real_escape_string($myfile);


    $import = $_POST['import'];
    $import = stripslashes($import);
    $import = mysql_real_escape_string($import);

    if($classname && $save)
    {
        $choose_db;
        $sql="INSERT INTO classes (`class`) VALUES ('$classname')";
        $res=mysql_query($sql, $connect) or die (mysql_error());

        if ($res)
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('Class added succefully');
                    window.location='../classes.php'
                </script>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script type=text/javascript'>
                    alert('Class not added');
                    window.location('../classes.php');
                </script";
        }
    }




    elseif ($import && $myfile)
    {
        echo $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

        if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
        {
            $thefile=fopen($filename, "r");

            while (($thedata = fgetcsv($thefile, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {
                $sql_file="INSERT INTO classes (`class`) VALUES ('$thedata[1]')";
                $res_file=mysql_query($sql_file, $connect) or die (mysql_error());

                if (!$res_file)
                {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                                alert ('Invalid file type!');
                                window.location = '../classes.php';
                        </script>                   
                    ";
                }
            }

            fclose($thefile);

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                        alert ('File Imported Successfully!');
                        window.location = '../classes.php';
                    </script>                   
            ";

        }
    }




    else
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                        alert('Fill the form or choose a CSV file');
                        window.location='../classes.php'
                </script>";
    }


?>
```

here is the html form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="addclass" action="popups/saveclass.php">

    <div style="margin:5px" class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-12">New Class Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" name="classname" class="form-control" placeholder="Class Name" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <center><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" id="submit" style="width:200px; height:30px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#002435; font-size:14px; cursor:pointer"/>
    </center>
</form> 

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="uploadcsv" action="popups/saveclass.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <br /><center>Or Upload CSV file</center><br />


    <div style="margin:5px" class="form-group">

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="file" name="myfile" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <center><input type="submit" name="import" value="Import" style="width:200px; height:30px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#002435; font-size:14px; cursor:pointer"/></center>

</form>
```

Comment: please post your HTML form so we can see how this gets posted.

Comment: Apparently you know what @Barmar is saying. You should check if `$[FILES]` is populated in your `else if`.

Comment: What if they upload a file but don't fill in `$import` and `$myfile`?

Comment: @Barmar I thought so too. but am looking at it and it looks just fine to me. I've added the code for the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File uploads are only in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`. So `$myfile =`$_POST['myfile'];`won't do anything, get rid of everything related to`$myfile`.

There's no need to call `stripslashes` or `mysql_real_escape_string` on `$_POST['import']`, since you're not storing it in the database.

You use `$_FILES['file']`, but the name of that input is `myfile`, so it should be `$_FILES['myfile']`.

So the code should be:

```
elseif (isset($_POST['import'], $_FILES['myfile'])) {
    echo $filename = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
    if ($_FILES["myfile"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```